# Why does this code create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript problem. I have a function that runs when I hit a button, the variables are changed via JavaScript. Everything in the function runs properly but this one last part:

```
else if (upgrade == "upgMiner4") {
var cost="500";
var qty="1";
var readCash=parseInt(document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML);
while (readCash >= cost) {
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML += "-"+cost;
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML += "+"+qty;
document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML);
}
}
```

When I run this code, it freezes and creates an infinite loop. I don't see the problem here, so I would like to know if you guys could help me, thanks!

-Zachucks

Comment: You appear to be eval'ing the contents of a HTML element. That's an interesting and potentially insecure thing to do. Can I ask why this route was chosen?

Comment: What would be a better way rather than evaluating the contents of an html element?

Comment: You appear to be using it like a variable, so just use variables :)

Comment: But I am changing the values of these variables in HTML, that is the whole point, is to be visual, so how would you do it? The variables are in HTML, not javascript, I use the javascript to change the HTML variables.

Comment: The intermediate step where the cash element has contents '1000-500' in gets immediately overwritten by the eval'd results of '500'. In that case, there is no point updating the html element until the result is known. eval() should be avoided at all costs. It allows for arbitrary code to be executed, which can be insecure.

Comment: Okay, so say in the event of adding 1 to a variable x in javascript, where x is the contents of an html object, what are you saying I should do? Because when I do document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += +1; and the initial variable of x is 1 it will output 11. So to make it 1+1=2, I have to evaluate it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").innerHTML) + 1;`

Comment: Thanks, that works, it also shortens my Javascript code by alot.

Comment: Makes it more secure to boot! Fantastic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code inside the while loop does nothing to update `readCash` or `cost`, so if the condition `(readCash >= cost)` is true, this will never change, and the while loop will never exit.

I should add that a reader cannot tell what the evals are evaluating--so it's hard to be sure what is going on.  However, notice you assign to `readCash` and `cost` exactly one time and that you never do this again.  So why would it change?

Answer (score 0):

Because you set readCash value only once and don't update it together with innerHTML with your div. That's why your loop doesn't end.

Working code:

```
while (readCash >= cost) {
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML += "-"+cost;
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML += "+"+qty;
document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("gpt").innerHTML);
readCash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

neither *readCash* or *cost* variable are changing in the last **while** loop. That's why you're facing a loop. Probably you have to increment/decrement *readCash* or *cost* vars with a logic you're missing. Or maybe you don't actually need a **while** statement, but simply an **if**